# What is the correct way to call a component method in many other components in React?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am using React with Meteor. I am currently building an app that has grown to have a sizeable number of components (some nesting quite deeply, like 5 or more levels).

I often find myself having to pass props from the parent all the way to the children, just to call a component method for a component that has been rendered in the topmost parent, like this:

**Parent File**

```
openDialog() {
  this.setState({ open: true });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={ this.state.open } />
      <ChildComponent openDialog={ this.openDialog.bind(this) } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <GrandChildComponent openDialog={ this.props.openDialog } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And so on, just to call the openDialog method defined right at the topmost parent.

---

This works if you only have one branch going deeper inwards. However if you have say, a login modal dialog which can be triggered from many different parts of a site (header, sidebar, inline links, etc), it is obviously impractical to pass in props this way into every single component which could possibly require the link (or not).

What is the correct (recommended) way to handle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution is to link your component to an external set of actions and an external State Manager. [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) architecure is used for that. And several frameworks, like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), help you integrate it with React.

With flux, you can dispatch an action (`openDialog` for example)  from every component without having to pass it through the whole tree of components.